# Print to a TSC TTP 244 Plus barcode printer using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, barcode

I am working on an inventory management system in Laravel for a client. For barcode generation I am currently using a package provided by dinesh on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/dinesh/barcode) which indeed generates the necessary barcode. I preferred HTML and SVG method for generation  since this allowed me to append necessary product information to the barcode.
However, I am not able to figure out how to print barcodes on a standard barcode printer. Currently I am using TSC TTP 244 Plus. Also, when I just scan the barcode on my laptop it works fine, but when I open the print preview then the scanner is unable to detect the barcode. I am aware that every printer would have its own resolution and font requirement but I don't know how to setup the right css for printing the barcode properly.

Any PHP based solution is fine. I just mentioned the barcode generator method I am using for reference. Any help here would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand, is the printer directly connected to the server that Laravel runs on or do you need to print them from the client's browser ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send raw printer commands to an installed printer.  I am currently using http://qzindustries.com/download.  However, you will not be able to use Chrome broswer for this because support of java is going away http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html

An alternative is http://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/php/